# Extract content of file and attach to a socket & send Socket Programming

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

What's the proper/most simple way to treat the contents of file as a data stream (User chooses buffer size) and send it as a UDP packet through a socket? And then record the number of bytes sent?
What's the correct way to approach this?
Current progress of my UDP Client.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PROTOPORT   33455 //Default Port Number
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *dHost;            //Pointer to Destination IP Address
    int port;               //Integer to hold Port Number
    char *host;             //Pointer to Host IP Address
    char *inputFile;        //Pointer to Input File Name
    char *outputFile;       //Pointer to Output File Name
    int sDescriptor;         //Socket Descriptor

    struct hostent  *ptrh;   /* pointer to a host table entry   */
    struct  protoent *ptrp;  /* pointer to a protocol table entry   */
    struct sockaddr_in sad; /* structure to hold an IP address  */

    dHost = argv[1];        //Server IP Address
    host =  argv[3];        //Client IP Address
    inputFile = argv[4];    //Input File Name
    outputFile = argv[5];   //Output File Name
    char buffer[atoi(argv[6])];   //Buffer

    //Map Port
    if (argc > 2) {
        port = atoi(argv[2]);
    } else {
        port = PROTOPORT;
    }
    if (port > 0)
        sad.sin_port = htons((u_short)port);
    else {
        fprintf(stderr,"bad port number %s\n",argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }

    //Map IP Address
    ptrh = gethostbyname(host);
    memcpy(&sad.sin_addr, ptrh->h_addr, ptrh->h_length);

    //Create UDP Socket
    sDescriptor = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, ptrp->p_proto);
    if (sDescriptor < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket creation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Connect
    if (connect(sDescriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&sad, sizeof(sad)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Connect failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Send


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You call `send()` and `recv().` What problem exactly have you had with that?

Comment: @EJP How would the packet size be determined through send?

Comment: You determine the packet size beforehand.  Allocate a buffer of that size, read some file data into it, and pass it and its size to `send()` (make sure you account for the possibility that the last buffer may have fewer bytes than the full buffer size). The UDP datagram payload that `send()` transmits will be as large as the buffer size you specify, so the receiver will know the buffer size simply by looking at the size of the datagram.  Repeat as needed for however many buffers it takes to read the entire file from beginning to end.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is my question. How can I allocate a buffer of that size with the contents in it? Can you quickly point me to a simple example?

Comment: @Aaron: Seriously?  You don't know how to allocate a byte array, or read from a file?  Then you need to stop what you are doing and learn how to write file I/O code before you then try to mix it with socket I/O code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PROTOPORT   33455 //Default Port Number
#define BUFSIZE     1024  //Default Buffer Size

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *dHost;            //Pointer to Destination IP Address
    int  port;              //Integer to hold Port Number
    char *host;             //Pointer to Host IP Address
    char *inputFile;        //Pointer to Input File Name
    char *outputFile;       //Pointer to Output File Name
    int  sDescriptor;       //Socket Descriptor
    char *buffer;           //Buffer
    int  bufferSize;        //Buffer allocated size, in bytes
    int  readSize;          //Buffer used size, in bytes

    struct hostent *ptrh;   // pointer to a host table entry
    struct sockaddr_in sad; // structure to hold an IPv4 address

    FILE *inFile;

    if (argc < 6) {
        fprintf(stderr,"not enough parameters\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    dHost = argv[1];        //Server IP Address
    port = atoi(argv[2]);   //Port
    if (port <= 0) port = PROTOPORT;
    host = argv[3];         //Client IP Address
    inputFile = argv[4];    //Input File Name
    outputFile = argv[5];   //Output File Name
    bufferSize = atoi(argv[6]);
    if (bufferSize <= 0) bufferSize = BUFSIZE;

    memset(&sad, 0, sizeof(sad));
    sad.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sad.sin_port = htons((u_short)port);

    //Map IP Address

    sad.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(dHost);
    if (sad.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE) {
        ptrh = gethostbyname(dHost);
        if (ptrh == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,"cannot resolve host %s\n", dHost);
            exit(1);
        }
        if (ptrh->h_addrtype != AF_INET) {
            fprintf(stderr,"host %s does not resolve to IPv4 address\n", dHost);
            exit(1);
        }
        memcpy(&sad.sin_addr, ptrh->h_addr, ptrh->h_length);
    }

    //Create UDP Socket
    sDescriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sDescriptor < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket creation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Connect
    if (connect(sDescriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&sad, sizeof(sad)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Connect failed\n");
        close(sDescriptor);
        exit(1);
    }

    inFile = fopen(inputFile, "rb");
    if (inFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open file %s\n", inputFile);
        close(sDescriptor);
        exit(1);
    }

    //Send

    buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot allocate buffer\n");
        fclose(inFile);
        close(sDescriptor);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1) {
        readSize = fread(buffer, 1, bufferSize, inFile);
        if (readSize <= 0) {
            if (ferror(inFile) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr,"Cannot read from file %s\n", inputFile);
                free(buffer);
                fclose(inFile);
                close(sDescriptor);
                exit(1);
            }
            break; 
        }

        if (send(sDescriptor, buffer, readSize, 0) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Send failed\n");
            free(buffer);
            fclose(inFile);
            close(sDescriptor);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    free(buffer);
    fclose(inFile);
    close(sDescriptor);

    return 0;
}
```